Create a Managed Package that uses Quotes even if Org does not have it enabled
I'm kind of new to developing a managed package. Currently working on a LWC with some Apex Controllers. One question I had is that I wanted to develop some features around Quotes. I noticed that if I were to create a scratch-org and try to deploy my code to it - it wouldn't work unless I enable Quotes in the org first.
An error like this would appear: Invalid type: QuoteDocument
I wanted to ask, is there anyway I can structure my Apex code so that if an org were to install my package, it would be installable even if they do not have quotes enabled?
Example:
[SELECT Id From Quote]

Yes, probably possible, but ideally you'd provide some examples on what you want to do. For a starter, for example have a look at this.

Hey @FelixvanHove I've added an example above, but basically when my LWC connects on an Opportunity apge, I want to make an Apex call that finds all associated Quote id's. However, I want this code to be deployable to orgs that may not have quotes enabled, in that situation I would do a check and return nothing.
Are you saying in your example, I should query the object dynamically instead of above example?

Please have a look at the link in my afore comment. Yes, dynamic SOQL is absolutely an option. This is just SObjects and Strings. (Use Database.query(...) and you get a QueryException, if the object doesn't exist - something you can catch.) But you can also do DML with this, just have a look at what
SObject has on offer. Not sure though, if I would recommend this.

@FelixvanHove Thanks for the help so far. I looked at the link in your first comment and tried replicating the suggested approach and it worked! However, I'm having trouble approaching writing tests for this. Ie if my one method returned all Quotes and manipulates the data in anyway, my test fails since I can't actually insert any test data into the Quotes object. Do you have any suggested approaches to this as well? Thanks!

My answer hopefully answers this question. Obviously any Assert makes only sense inside of the block that is not the "Never mind" block ;-)

One can work with SObjects without using their explicit types. A similar question has been answered by the renowned sfdcfox here.
Query Quotes:
String query = 'SELECT Name, Status, GrandTotal FROM Quote';
try {
    List<SObject> sObjects = Database.query(query);
    for(SObject so : sObjects) {
        System.debug(so.get('Id') + ': ' + so.get('GrandTotal'));
    }
} catch(QueryException e) {
    System.debug('Never mind');
}

One can equally well insert them:
Type t = Type.forName('Quote'); 
if(t!=null) {
    SObject so=(SObject) t.newInstance(); 
    so.put('Name', 'Psst');
    so.put('OpportunityId', '006AU00000G5F6sYAF');
    insert so;
} else {
    System.debug('Never mind');
}

This is not meant to recommend this for the given context. It really depends on circumstances. Just to demonstrate the possibility.

Short Answer
No, when your package is installed Salesforce compiles the entire source code and if a type does not exist it fails
Long Answer
This is a ubiquitous problem for ISV developers, so much so that there is an unofficial tool used by many package developers to assist with dealing with specific ISV problems called CumulusCI
Alongside CumulusCI, there is a hostable service to manage installing packages that require custom installation steps called MetaDeploy
With MetaDeploy and CumulusCI you can define "Preflight Checks" that do custom pre installation checks that you define, which you could write a check for to make sure Quotes are enabled.
Preflight checks are not documented well and will require a little research on github looking at existing examples.
I realize this is throwing a kitchen sink at a small problem, but considering adopting CumulusCI for your solution may add value and solve future problems you may not even be aware of with your solution
